# Same counter for different tcolorbox theorems

Tags: theorems, tcolorbox

I have two different types of tcbtheorems: theorem and lemma, defined as below.

```
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{some config options}{thm}
\newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{lemma}{Lemma}{some config options}{lem}
```

If I, somewhere in my document, have

```
\begin{theorem}{}{}
theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}{}{}
lemma
\end{lemma}
```

It produces "Theorem 1.1" and "Lemma 1.1," whereas I'd like it to produce "Theorem 1.1" and then "Lemma 1.2."

Comment: Please provide us with a complete compilable example, which starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`. (And if I am not mistaken this has not too much to do with `tcolorbox`, rather you have to use a shared counter for your theorems.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the option `use counter from=theorem` when defining the new lemma `\newtcbtheorem`

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{theorems}
    \newtcbtheorem[number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}{}{thm}
    \newtcbtheorem[number within=section,
                  use counter from=theorem % <----------------
                  ]{lemma}{Lemma}{}{lem}

\begin{document}
\section{title section}
\begin{theorem}{}{}
theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{lemma}{}{}
lemma
\end{lemma}
\end{document}
```

[image]